# Regex for Alphabet characters in order (without skipping letters)

Tags: regex

I have trouble writing the correct regular expression for following conditions:

-Word should contain letter from alphabet, for example from A to E

-Letters should be in alphabetic order, but without skipping between two letters! , for example: ABCD is a correct word, ACD is not because B is missing

-It can begin with whatever letter from the alphabet, for example: BCD is valid, as well as DE, but again BCE is not because D is missing

-No letter repeating, for example: AAB is not valid, DEE is not valid

I've tried with following logic :
^A?B?C?D?E?$

But with this I can skip between letters which is not allowed.
What can I try to make between letters not skippable?

Comment: It is not a good regex task, because you will have to use a lot of alternatives and optional groups, `^(?:A(?:B(?:C(?:DE?)?)?)?|B(?:C(?:DE?)?)?|C(?:DE?)?|DE?)$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IqgqEL/1).

Comment: mine is shorter (and simpler) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, regex does not support (x+1) type of computation.
However, you could do this ugly thing:

```
^(?:A|AB|ABC|ABCD|ABCDE|B|BC|BCD|BCDE|C|CD|CDE|D|DE|E)$
```